Non-interacting wavefunction for indistinguishable particles
In Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by Griffiths and Schroeter, it is stated that for indistinguishable particles, we have two available choices of wavefunction:
$$\psi_{\pm}(\vec r_1\cdot\vec r_2)=A[\psi_a(\vec r_1)\psi_b(\vec r_2)\pm\psi_b(\vec r_1)\psi_a(\vec r_2)]$$
Where the subscripts $a$ and $b$ refer to the particles and $1$ and $2$ to their positions.
If the $\psi_a$ and $\psi_b$ are normalised and orthogonal, then to find the constant $A$ we set
$$\int\psi_{\pm}^*\psi_{\pm}d^3r_1d^3r_2=1$$
This gives
$$A^2\int[\psi_a(\vec r_1)\psi_b(\vec r_2)\pm\psi_b(\vec r_1)\psi_a(\vec r_2)]^*[\psi_a(\vec r_1)\psi_b(\vec r_2)\pm\psi_b(\vec r_1)\psi_a(\vec r_2)]d^3r_1d^3r_2=1$$
If we assume that $\psi_a$ is only a function of the position of particle one and similarly for particle $b$ then the cross terms are zero and we get $2A^2=1$. But how can we justify this assumption? Wouldn't the wavefunctions of both particles influence each other?

Wavefunctions do not "influence each other" under the assumption that the particles are independent.  "Independent particles" means precisely that the two wavefunctions are independent one from the other.

I don't understand your final expression. There appears to be a missing bracket, and there is no equality. It's just an integral.

"But how can we justify this assumption?" What assumption? What does your word "this" refer to?

You end up with
$$1=A^2[2\pm2(\int\psi_a(\vec r)\psi_b^*(\vec r) d^3r)^2]$$
The integral is $\delta_a^b$, because the individual wave functions are orthonormal. Notice that when $a=b$, then $A$ can have any value for fermions and $A=1/2$ for bosons.
